# Javascript client & asp.net event handler timing issues - how to solve?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

Simple web site with master page and multiple child pages.

In page_load, master page looks for session variable containing a value and if it's there, uses

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SessionAlert", "SessionExpireAlert(" + sessionTimeout + ");", true);
```

This kicks off a timeout alert, which works fine.

There is a server-side button on one child page that effectively ends the user interaction on the page and leaves a message stating "go and log in again if you want to do more stuff". When this button is clicked, I want to clear out the session variable (easy) and end the running timeout warning alert script (not so easy).

As the Master "page_load" event fires BEFORE the button handler, at the time the page reloads, it restarts the timeout script.  When it hits the button event handler and clears the session variable, it's too late as the script is already running.

I've tried using "registerclientscriptblock" to inject immediate javascript to call the "clearTimeout()" client side function I have, but it doesn't seem to be able to find the function which exists on the master page and errors.

This seems to be a classic "chicken and egg" scenario and I can't see the wood for the trees. Could someone please point me in the right direction here before I drive myself mad!?

edited to add bit of javascript code:

Currently the master page function "SessionExpireAlert" referenced by the page_load code contains among other things this:

```
                 window.updateInterval = setInterval(function () {
                     seconds--;
                     document.getElementById("idleTime").innerHTML = convertTime(seconds);
                     document.getElementById("expireTime").innerHTML = convertTime(seconds);
                 }, 1000);
```

Comment: The web page should be able to access any variables created by a script injected by the master page, so it should be a simple case of assigning the value of `setTimeout` to a var and then clearing it from a script inject by the page afterwards.

Comment: I know it *should* but it doesn't!  See code added at bottom of OP above.  If , in my button event, I use registerclientscriptblock with "alert(window.updateInterval");" then the alert box pops up with "undefined" but if I do it from the master page javascript it shows me "2".

Comment: Use `RegisterStartupScript`, the same as in the master page.  The way you're doing it just puts the script in the page at whatever point you tell it to, whereas startup scripts are put at the end of the body, in order.

Comment: Well swipe me, it was as simple as that!  Thank you - propose it as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: It's a bit of an abstract concept, making it difficult to explain, but I've had a go.  Glad it sorted your problem anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegisterStartupScript` will add the script to the end of the body, so the DOM is ready when it runs.  As long as you always use `RegisterStartupScript` after that then the scripts will be added and executed in the order you create them.

Basically, `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is most likely going to place the script *before* any scripts added with `RegisterStartupScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting this in Page_PreRender instead:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SessionAlert", "SessionExpireAlert(" + sessionTimeout + ");", true);
```

With an appropriate check first to see if it is necessary?